# Removing generated stylesheet reference

Tags: c#, dynamic, stylesheet

In the Page_Load of my MasterPage, i've programmatically added a reference to a styleheet:

```
HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
css.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
css.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
css.Attributes.Add("id", "admin_style");
css.Href = "Style_Admin.css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

Now i wish to remove this reference again, but i can't seem to get it working.
I've tried a simple findcontrol on the id and .Remove(), but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how to remove the reference?

Comment: Did you remove this code? if you did, recompile, and refresh your cache for the page (Ctrl+F5 in the browser)

Comment: That's not what i meant lol :-P 
I wish to remove the reference to the stylesheet programmatically.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12705583/how-can-i-find-and-remove-css-references-in-html-head

Comment: You want me to locate my stylesheet reference using regex? All i want to do, is locate my stylesheet control, then i'm good to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlLink css = new HtmlLink();
css.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
css.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
css.Href = "Style_Admin.css";
css.ID = "admin_style";

Page.Header.Controls.Add(css);
```

and remove via

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Page.Header.Controls)
{
    var htmlLink = ctrl as HtmlLink;
    if (htmlLink != null)
    {
        if (htmlLink.ID == "admin_style")
            Page.Header.Controls.Remove(htmlLink);
    }
}
```